# Replacing backslashes in Strings

Tags: groovy

Is it possible replace all backslash `\\` to forward slash `/` in Groovy?

```
String someString = rootDir
someString.replace("\\","////")
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: maybe you meant Groovy String?

Comment: @tim_yates If you remove all references to gradle in the question, maybe you should keep the gradle tag? OP was asking the question for a gradle script to start with.

Comment: But none of this is anything to do with gradle afaict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def someString = "a\\b\\c\\d/e/f/g/h"
println someString
println someString.replaceAll("\\\\", "/")
```

produces the output:

```
a\b\c\d/e/f/g/h
a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h
```

Note that `replaceAll` does not modify the string in place, but returns a new modified string.

Comment: You can also use _"dollar slashy"_ strings to cut down the escaping on the backslashes: `$/a\b\c\d/e/f/g/h/$.replaceAll($/\\/$, '/')`